# Set Windows 10 Bootloader to Metro Style

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, windows-10, bootloader, modern-ui

I'm using Windows 10, upgrading from Windows 7. I have Ubuntu installed in my hard disk, so I want to boot Ubuntu from Windows bootloader.

After adding Ubuntu to Windows bootloader, I rebooted, however I was shown the old-style bootloader.

[image: bootloader]

After that, I run the command `bcdedit` and this is the message:

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {f5875617-3757-11e5-88d8-a6b54dbf2793}
displayorder            {current}
                        {fb8b2b2f-4207-11e5-9410-a41f72613d02}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30
displaybootmenu         Yes

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \WINDOWS\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 10
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {28e490f6-359e-11e5-a84f-d057d52065ca}
recoveryenabled         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \WINDOWS
resumeobject            {f5875617-3757-11e5-88d8-a6b54dbf2793}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
hypervisorlaunchtype    Off

Real-mode Boot Sector
---------------------
identifier              {fb8b2b2f-4207-11e5-9410-a41f72613d02}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \NST\AutoNeoGrub0.mbr
description             Ubuntu 15.04
```

Even if I change `bootmenupolicy`, the boot manager is still the old one, and not the new metro-style one. How can I change the boot manager to the metro-style one?

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 8 and up boot manager, the bcd parameter

```
bootmenupolicy          Standard
```

is the "default" then your bcd entry wouldn't be necessary.

It seems to me your problem is that for some reason you are still running your old Windows 7 Boot Manager; then you will always see the old style of menu no matter what you define for bootmenupolicy at bcd level.

Comment: I successfully restored the metro boot manager using easybcd console (I seems not to be able to do it in normal cmd.exe, even using administrator). I'm not sure what does this mean, but I'm looking forward to some other solutions.

Comment: you can compare both bcd then and see if some additional key is necessary. Please write your findings here; it might help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not accepting my own answer; I'm waiting for answers with more explanation and evidence.

I've used the easybcd console to run the command `bcdboot C:\windows` and successfully restored the metro-style bootloader. The current message by running `bcdedit` is:

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-us
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {fb8b2b32-4207-11e5-9410-a41f72613d02}
displayorder            {current}
                        {fb8b2b2f-4207-11e5-9410-a41f72613d02}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 10
locale                  en-us
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \windows
resumeobject            {fb8b2b32-4207-11e5-9410-a41f72613d02}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard

Real-mode Boot Sector
---------------------
identifier              {fb8b2b2f-4207-11e5-9410-a41f72613d02}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \NST\AutoNeoGrub0.mbr
description             Ubuntu 15.04
```

A clear list of difference can be found [here](https://www.diffchecker.com/gub0f7tb).